# Can StyleCop automatically fix anything?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, shortcut, stylecop

I've decided to start running StyleCop on a medium sized project and am getting over 1000 warnings.

Is there a quick easy way to fix most of these warnings? Most of the warnings could easily have been automated to resolve and would save me a lot of time.

Comment: How can I make StyleCop show more than 1000 Warnings at once?

Comment: It's good to note that one fix can get rid of many, many stylecop warnings.  E.g., putting a .ctor at the bottom of a large file will generate a warning for each item above the .ctor that shouldn't be, but moving the .ctor to the top of the class is a single fix.  I've killed off 200+ warnings in a single file in 15 or fewer minutes because of stuff like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This doesn't exactly "automatically fix anything" but there is a [StyleCop plug-in](https://web.archive.org/web/20140124045330/http://consultingblogs.emc.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2008/11/06/new-release-of-stylecop-for-resharper.aspx) for Resharper on [Github](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop.ReSharper) that will automatically highlight the style errors in your code.

***Update:** According to the [StyleCop for ReSharper website](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop.ReSharper), ReSharper now provides an increasing number of [Quick-Fixes](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Quick-Fixes) for StyleCop errors. You select a quick-fix from the list and the problem will be resolved automatically.*

Comment: Set up your code cleanup profile, and you can use CTRL + E + F to automatically reformat any file to fix all errors.

Comment: (That's a R# thing anyway, but with StyleCop-4-ReSharper it also fixes style violations).

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2019, there is https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers

Answer (score 30):

**No, frustratingly**. That's why Style Cop is counter-productive. Consistent formatting looks nice, but there's little productivity benefit to it (what really makes code hard to read is length and [indirection](http://zedshaw.com/essays/indirection_is_not_abstraction.html)). Perfect spacing is not worth spending hours adjusting lines by hand.

Of course, if there were an *automated* tool to achieve consistent formatting, I'd hook it up post-check-in, and let it help me. But Style Cop is made by sadists. Presumably their conversation went like this:

> Bob: Using pattern matching, the software identifies ugly code
>   Charlie: —and fixes it!
>   Bob: No, it prints a message about each transgression
>   Charlie: —and then the user right-clicks to fix them all?
>   Bob: No, it scolds them 'invalid spacing around the comma'
>   Charlie: —and then explains how to fix it?
>   Bob: No, that's in a separate document
>   Charlie: —on Google?
>   Bob: No.

I hate Style Cop. It's below a minimum viable product.

Comment: It's a fun answer but there are tools to help with just what you described - white space formatting.

Comment: Hahaha. this makes me laugh. +1. I am very much amused

Comment: StyleCop Analyzers definitely lets you fix all transgressions of a rule in a single click throughout the solution. Not sure what you're talking about there

Comment: This is amusing! The answer ofthelit gives an image how to fix it. Myself, I missed the popout window. Was initially very frustrated. It's nice to know there's an answer :)

Answer (score 25):

Nowadays you can use the [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers) NuGet package in your projects.

[image: NuGet Package Manager available StyleCop.Analyzers update]

Updating the package can result in a lot of new warnings.

[image: Visual Studio Error List warnings of 'Documentation text should end with a period']

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> shows available quick fixes. A fix can be applied to the whole **document**, **project** or **solution** at once.

[image: Visual Studio quick fix. Marked 'Fix all occurrences in' options]

A *Preview Changes* window lets you deselect the lines to resolve manually.

[image: Window Preview Changes - Fix all occurrences]

[CodeMaid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid) is a good tool to fix formatting errors in batch or automatically.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This works regardless of editor (no ReSharper needed) and is the official method

Comment: While this works fine for single type of error/warning i'm missing the feature to do that for every kind of error. Is that possible?

Comment: This works and should be accepted answer.

Comment: While being able to fix the entire solution at once is a good step, is there any way to get this to run as a pre-commit hook, the way that Prettier/Eslint/etc are used in the JS ecosystem? It's absurd to me that such a mature language doesn't have such simple QoL tools.

Comment: Great answer, also work's with Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Great answer, works like a charm on my VS 2019

Answer (score 7):

[StyleCopFixer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ea197362-8fa1-44c8-8be2-e2b87d12be2a/?SRC=Home) automatically fixes StyleCop exceptions **within Visual Studio IDE** for **C# Only**.

Errors currently catered for are:

1. SA1001
2. SA1516
3. SA1513
4. SA1508
5. SA1507
6. SA1505
7. SA1309
8. SA1210
9. SA1202
10. SA1200
11. SA1106
12. SA1101
13. SA1025
14. SA1013
15. SA1012
16. SA1009
17. SA1008
18. SA1633
19. SA1003
20. SA1005
21. SA1600 (for properties only)
22. SA1121

Comment: it has really bad reviews. and, it only says compliant with vs 2010.

Answer (score 3):

There is a project in codeplex which does some automatic fix based on stylecop warning. It is not complete however...

see: http://stylefix.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

[Code Maid](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) does some Stylecop fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, right now, I don't know of any automatic tools to fix things entirely.

However, if you setup Visual Studio's formatting options (and Resharper's, if you have that) for code formatting to match the style cop guidelines, cleanups get a bit easier.

Once you've done that, you can go into a file and do Edit->Advanced->Format Document (or the keyboard shortcut, which varies with your shortcut settings - mine is Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D).  This will fix quite a few of the style cop warnings, especially if you have resharper + the stylecop plugin.  It won't fix all of them, but in many cases, it's taken the number of warnings in a file from hundreds down to tens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Resharper you can download a StyleCop plugin for Resharper which features some automatic fixes.
[StyleCop for Resharper on codeplex.](http://www.codeplex.com/StyleCopForReSharper)

Answer (score -1):

1. Turn off the warnings! Not recommended, but you could use this in the short term until you get a bulk of the issues resolved.
2. Write a program to fix some of the simpler warnings, or use find/replace
3. Use code snippets to help with things like file header documentation

There was mention on the StyleCop [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/24/future-plans.aspx) regarding implementing auto fixing for rules

Also check out the [entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/11/11/introducing-stylecop-on-legacy-projects.aspx) on the blog regarding integrating in to an existing large project.

Note: It seems that StyleCop only returns around 1000 warnings, so you will continue to get this number even after fixing a heap.

Comment: If you are going to downvote something, it seems only fair to provide an explanation if the reason is not obvious.

Comment: The question is about using StyleCop and fix the code. Not about how to get rid of the warnings.