# Get Stylecop to automatically fix issues in c#

Tags: c#, stylecop

Is it possible to get style cop to fix any issues?  Or any other tool to fix the style cop issues?

I understand that some of the issues may be complicated to code for but this one "SA1101: The call to UpdateButtonLocations must begin with the 'this.' prefix to indicate that the item is a member of the class."  looks like it should be fairly trivial to fix.

From reading around I think Resharper can be integrated so that it warns you of any issues as you code, and while this is useful it won't help me on an existing project with 100s of warnings similar to the one above!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832209/can-stylecop-automatically-fix-anything

I believe this answers your question with a "maybe".

Comment: @Tim, I saw that question, but since that was posted in 2009 I was hoping there might have been some updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a style cop addin for ReSharper available (Look [here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)). With that you can have the option to clean it manually or within the "Clean Code" functionality of ReSharper do it automatically.

Comment: The "Clean Code" functionality sounds exactly like what I'm looking for.  I don't have access to resharper at the moment, but soon hopefully.

Comment: You can test 30 days for free, and the style cop plugin is free ware.

Comment: Good to know, will try it out in the new year. :)

Answer (score 1):

Resharper does have a clean solution that will do this to all files in the solution. Good idea or bad idea is up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many refactoring options built into Visual Studio 2010, and add-ons like Resharper (commercial) add many more.

These are mostly automatic and will speed up fixing such issues.